# How can I duplicate a UV map on the same object?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I want to have an object with two identical UV maps, but I don't know how to duplicate them. I feel like the answer is simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a [new uvmap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel) it will duplicate the selected uvmap.

[image: add new uvmap]

If you want them to stay identical there is no advantage to having multiple uvmaps, the same map can be used for multiple image textures and in multiple materials.

[image: multiple images using one uvmap]

Comment: Even when baking AO in Cycles? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zum2jlruecw&t=5s

Comment: @drpeppercan a uvmap is data that translates a point on a model to a position on an image. There is no connection between a uvmap and an image so you can use the same uvmap for the bake image as well as the source image, just be sure that each is using a different image. By using the same uvmap, the source and the baked image will "align".